# What was Bran's plan to kill the Night King?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Bran went out of his way to be alone in the Godswood so he could meet the Night King.  When the Night King does finally meet him, Bran just looks at him and doesn't do anything.

> If Arya had not come and save him it seems like he would be dead.

What was his plan?

Comment: Bran was never going to fight the NK. His purpose was to lure the NK out into the open where someone else could get him. I believe this is covered in the previous episode.

Comment: The showrunners explained it: [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/freefolk/comments/bjkyln/so_we_go_into_hbo_and_tell_them_bran_has_an_idea/)

Comment: Bran's inaction begs the question: Why would the Night King want him dead? And if he did, why not just send a bunch of minions to take care of him? He's a helpless cripple, after all.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen _"He wants to erase this world, and I am its memory."_

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that doesn't explain why hordes of minions couldn't kill Bran as well as the Night King himself

Comment: @Nacht The Night King wanted to kill Bran himself but that's out of scope of this question here.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - *He's a helpless cripple* - That's why I think it would have been awesome if Bran had suddenly flicked some kind of throwing knife into the Night King right before he landed his killing blow. It would have subverted the expectations of everybody who dismissed Bran as a "helpless cripple"

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen It's been discussed endlessly. It's not yet clear why NK needed to kill Bran in person, ASAP, or if he actually needed to do those things at all. There may be a reason which will be revealed later, there may be a reason cut from the final show, and it may just be bad plotting/writing.

Comment: How was Bran going to kill the Night King? Two words: delegation.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The plan is made clear in the previous episode. The idea was to have Bran lightly defended with others close by, so that when the Night King comes to him, they can rush in and attack the Night King.

> **Jaime:** So, what can we do?
>
> **Jon:** The Night King made them all. They follow his command. If he falls. Getting to him may be our best chance.
>
> **Jaime:** If that's true, he'll never expose himself.
>
> **Bran:** Yes, he will. He'll come for me.
>
> [...]
>
> **Jon:** We'll put you in the crypt, where it's safest.
>
> **Bran:** No. We need to lure him into the open before his army destroys us all. I'll wait for him in the Godswood.
>
> **Sansa:** You want us to use you as bait? We're not leaving you alone out there.
>
> **Theon:** He won't be. I'll stay with him. With the Ironborn.
>
> [...]
>
> **Jon:** We need to be near him. Not too near, or the Night King won't come. But close enough to pursue him when he does.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 2, "A Knight of the Seven Kingdoms"</sub>

Comment: As with most of the Battle of Winterfell, it was a pretty bad plan. But no denying that it was what they came up with.

Comment: But, was this Bran's actual plan, or the official plan so that everything got along as actually planned?

Comment: @Bernat Technically the "official" plan but the difference is negligible in the end.

Comment: Eh, call it a bad plan if you want, but it technically worked. Bran lures Night King into open Godswood, where someone comes along and kills him. Done and done :)

Answer (score 2):

Bran doesn't plan normally; he watches, and then applies subtle influence where needed, while trying to not confuse people into doubting their own free will. He continually checks the future to see how everything plays out, and uses his words to nudge the future in a particular direction. He doesn't say too much, but what he does say is usually meaningful (except for a few times where he's just trying to be creepy).

While Bran was in a warg-state in the last moments as the Night King approached, he was probably checking the future to make sure things were going to end up the way he wanted.

Comment: I don't think there was any hint anywhere to that Bran could see the future to any degree, not even the tiniest. He is the Three-eyed Raven: he sees everything ever happened, but that's it. Not what's going to happen. Prove me wrong and I'll fully withdraw everything I said, but this answer is pure speculation without any actual base, and doesn't comply with what we know about the Three-eyed Raven at all.

Comment: @Neinstein Bran has greensight - https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Greensight - which allows visions of the future, present, and past. I think that symbolically, the three eyes of the raven correspond to these three "directions" in time. In the show Bran makes several references about seeing the future.